# Creating an array with unknown size of input files

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I newer in C language. I could not solve my problem. I have a input file, let's say **input.txt**. We know there are 4 column on every line. Nevertheless, we do not know how many lines are there. I give you sample input.txt:

```
Student,James,12,65
Teacher,Jane,23,60
Teacher,Michael,30,75
Student,Erric,15,73
```

First column can be 2 different things like student or teacher. 2nd column will be unique. No repeated names. 3rd column will be ages of the person's. 4th column will be weights. Also, I am trying to make 2D array. So, my goal is:

```
arrName = {{Student, James, 12, 65}, {Teacher,Jane,23,60}, {Teacher,Michael,30,75}, {Student, Erric, 15,73}}
```

I am trying to create like this array. The array must be dynamically. because we do not know how many lines are there. I could not split the every line by commas. I have tried `strdot`. how can I parse the lines with comma, and add them into 2D array? Also, I got confused about pointers. While creating 2D array, do we have to use like `char **arrPtr;`? Or using like `*arrPtr` is enough for creating 2D array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLUMN 4        //We know that there are 4 column in chars.txt file.

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char *arrName;
    int nameLines;

    arrName = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char ) );

    FILE *FileName;

    FileName = fopen(argv[1], "r");


    if (FileName == NULL) {
        printf("The Name file could not open!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    else{
        char c;

        while ( (c == fgetc(FileName)) != EOF ) {
            if (c == '\n') {
                nameLines++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", nameLines);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I could not continue after else statement. Can you help me?

Comment: Please give me sample codes. Because I understand better in this way

Comment: Since you do not know the size of your data beforehand you have to allocate your memory dynamically, using `malloc` and `realloc`. Start allocating a certain chunk, and when your data becomes too large, increase the chunk calling `realloc`. If you are not only new to C but also to dynamic memory management you probably should not yet program such tasks. Sorry, I don't have time to provide “sample” code.

Comment: @Renardo can you write sample code when you have time?

Comment: OK, I try to put it more clearly: your question looks like you want other people to do your work. StackOverflow expects askers to invest reasonable “own effort” before asking a question, and to provide the results along with the question, to avoid duplicate work. But your question specifies nothing but them problem. Try your own solution, post it here, and point out where the problems are. Then your chances to get help are a lot bigger.

Comment: @Renardo I have written some codes and I have editted my question. Can you look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a bunch of errors in your code like this for example.

`while ( (c == fgetc(FileName)) != EOF ) {`  -> `Comparison of constant -1 with boolean expression is always true`

So let's start fresh. This is how I would read a comma separated file and dynamically allocate memory to an array of ´read´ objects. It's actually less lines of code then you would expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLUMNS 4
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100 //Enter the maximum characters allowed as profession and name

typedef struct theDAta{
    char type[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
    char name[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
    unsigned int age;
    unsigned int weight;
}theData;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    theData* allDataPtr=malloc(1);  //Pointer to all entries
    theData currentData;    //The current read data
    int currentBlock=0;     //the index currently 'active'

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("The file you provided can't be read!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d\n", currentData.type, currentData.name,&currentData.age,&currentData.weight) == COLUMNS) {
        allDataPtr=realloc(allDataPtr, sizeof(theData)*(currentBlock+1));
        if (!allDataPtr) {exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} //Memory allocation failure. Ok so here i lost my pointer to the previous memory.. However we let the OS garbage collect us.
        memcpy(allDataPtr+currentBlock++, &currentData, sizeof(currentData));
    }

    for (int x=0; x<currentBlock; x++) {
        printf("Profession: %s\nName: %s\nAge: %d\nWeight: %d\n\n",allDataPtr[x].type,allDataPtr[x].name,allDataPtr[x].age,allDataPtr[x].weight);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(allDataPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

So what I do is to create a struct containing the stuff I want to populate from the file. Then I populate that object and extend the memory with the size of that object and then copy the read data to the end of that memory block.. That's basically it... Hope you get great grades :) !!

/Anders

**EDIT**

Was a bit bored this evening, so let's shave the code... And humm, well. This is not part of my official answer :-) but you could bling it like this (it's actually also skipping one layer of memory copy :) and the engine is 3 lines of C code if you define a line of C code delimiter as ';'->

```
typedef struct j{
    char t[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
    char n[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int w;
}j;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    j* g;
    int l=0;
    FILE *h;
    if((!(h=fopen(argv[1],"r"))||(!(g=malloc(sizeof(j))))))exit(-1);
    while(fscanf(h,"%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d\n",g[l].t,g[l].n,&g[l].a,&g[l].w)==COLUMNS)if(!(g=realloc(g,sizeof(j)*(++l+1))))exit(-1);
    for(int x=0;x<l;x++)printf("Profession: %s\nName: %s\nAge: %d\nWeight: %d\n\n",g[x].t,g[x].n,g[x].a,g[x].w);
    fclose(h);
    free(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want to ask that can I group of data according to their status(Student or teacher) ? I mean, if the person is student, pass this person to **student struct**, if the person is teacher, pass this person to **teacher struct**. Maybe, control this with if, else statement. I thinked that I'll create 1 general struct  as you did, then I will create two array(student and teacher), then I'll pass these their structs(student struct and teacher struct). But this way so bad! do u have any idea?

Comment: The architecture depends on how you are going to work with the data after the ingest. For example if you just want to parse the data once. like  print all teachers then all students. Then i personally would keep everything mixed. However if you repeatedly traverse the list I would either sort it the way I wanted alternatively make two lists.

Comment: To make it a bit more clear.

1. Use the same struct and all data mixed if you read occasionally and the data mass is small

2. Use the same struct but two or more data pointers one for teacher and one for students or however you want to separate the data.

3. Use the same struct and one data pointer but sort the data according how you want to access the data in what order.

It all comes down to. How do you want to work with the data when you ingested it.